# VSCode set workspace conda environment?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a setting in vscode to tell it that I want a conda environment to be the default workspace / project wide?

Comment: set the python interpreter path setting in your global `settings.json`

Comment: @rioV8 but what if I want to change it per project?

Comment: you are mixing up `virtual environment` and `workspace`, they are not the same

Comment: @rioV8 I have a project which I open with the workspace, I want that project to use an env in that workspace. How can I set a directory specific environment?

Comment: set the setting `python.pythonPath` to the full file path to the `python.exe` in this environment, if needed do this by hand, and do this in `.vscode/settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that it's much too late to be any use to the original OP now, but I hope this helps someone else later:

I'm assuming that the OP is asking for the following:
When I open VSCode, and I select the folder that I want to use for my project and its contents, then for that folder (read "project" in OP's terminology), whenever I open a new terminal (it opens in the root of that folder by default) then I want it to open in a Conda (Anaconda) virtual environment named "XYZ".

If this is the case then the simplest way to achieve this is by going to the command pallete (Command+Shift+P on a Mac, Control+Shift+P on Windows (?)), and going to 'Python: Select Interpreter'.  There will be a list that's then presented with all of your 'base' python versions that you have installed as well as any Conda environments that are available.  Click to select whichever one you want.  It may take a second or two to set it up (a little info panel on the bottom will say something like 'installing Python' or similar), and then every time you open a terminal in that folder it will automatically activate the Conda environment, which will be signified with a little (XYZ) at the start of the terminal line.